# How does multi-core architecture work with regard to parellelism?

Tags: cpu, multi-core, parallel-processing

I think I am correct in saying that scheduling is the/a main principle of the single core CPU, where the CPU is interrupted when switching from processing one set of instructions belonging to one program to another set of instructions. You can directly control this interrupt in assembly language.

So how about a multi-core CPU and hence parallelism, ultimately a framebuffer can send  one stream after the other to the screen, so how can multi-core be an advantage.

Comment: Huh? How did framebuffers get into it?

Answer (score 0):

Multi-core is an advantage because you can do something else *without* having to stop the thing you were already doing. Sure, you can always interrupt one bit of work to do some other bit of work that's more important. But assuming that first bit of work still needs to get done, it would be better not to have to. With more than one core, you are much less likely to have to put current work aside.